# What is an eight-by-eight-foot duct-tape?

Tags: grammar, numerals

What would an eight-by-eight-foot duct-tape be? Is it simply an eight foot long tape?

Comment: Interesting. Duct tape usually comes in 50 or 60 yard lengths so perhaps there is a different meaning. Where did you hear/read the phrase?

Comment: In a book called Reborn, by C. C. Hunter.

Comment: The heroine uses duct tape to wrap someone up? Can you edit your question and quote the paragraph? Context may help determine the meaning.

Comment: Oh, I just got it! It's an eight-by-eight-foot duct-tape BALL. So the ball is eight-by-eight foot. Thanks for the help, and sorry to bother.

Comment: No problem. An 8x8 duct tape ball - that would be a hoot!

Comment: I wonder if C.C. Hunter took geometry in high school.

Comment: Sorely tempted to use this new, innovative measurement system within earshot of my engineering friends, and watch their ears steam. Also, that is a hell of a lot of duct tape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment by the OP:

> Oh, I just got it! It's an eight-by-eight-foot duct-tape BALL. So the ball is eight-by-eight foot. Thanks for the help, and sorry to bother.

A ball is not 8 feet by 8 feet. What does that mean? That is applying two linear measurements to a sphere. We can *guess* what it might mean, such as 8 feet tall and 8 feet wide, but the the norm would be to say it was a *duct tape ball with an 8 foot diameter.*